# Can I use an html tag as selector in ViewChildren

Tags: angular6

I want to make all `<p>` in the template have `font-variant` `small-caps`. Can I pass an `html` to `ViewChildren`? I have seen examples where template reference variables or components are passed but haven't seen an example where the selector passed to `ViewChildren` is an `html` tag or a `css` class.

```
template: `<p>
  I am a static component
</p>
<p>
I am another para but I have an id (template reference variable) #pref. I got my blue color using ViewChild and Renderer2
</p>
<p>
  All paragraphs are small-caps because using ViewChildren and Renderer2, the style was set to bold
  </p>`
```

.ts file

```
import { Component,ViewChild, ViewChildren, QueryList,ElementRef,Renderer2,OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';
  @ViewChildren("p") paraList:QueryList<any>; /*I SUPPOSE I CANT DO THIS AS P IS INTERPRETED AS TEMPLATE REFERENCE VARIABLE AND NOT <P>*/
  constructor(private renderer:Renderer2){

  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){ //QueryList becomes available now
    this.paraList.forEach(para =>{this.renderer.addClass(para,'boldClass')})
  }

}
```

css

```
.boldClass{
  font-variant: small-caps;
}
```